# Substract in Mips

Tags: assembly, mips, qtspim

The problem appears when I wait for the result of the substraction to appear but instead it shows me 0. Not x-a as I hoped it will.

```
.data


strin: .asciiz "type two integers\n\n\n" 

strout: .asciiz "the result of the substract is:"

a: .word 0

x: .word 1



.text

main:

li $v0, 4                                                                          
la $a0,strin                                                                 
syscall  

li $v0, 5
syscall
sw $t0,a

li $v1,5
syscall
sw $t1,x


sub $t1,$t1,$t0                                      


li $v0, 4                                                                          
la $a0,strout                                                                                   
syscall

move $a0, $t1                   
li $v0, 1                        
syscall

li $v0,10                                               
syscall
```

Comment: You might want to consider *why* you are storing the input into memory. (Hint: the `syscall` may clobber registers)

Comment: Please do not vandalize your post.

Comment: Do not vandalize your own questions please. That's disrespectful against the people that took the efforts to answer your question!

Comment: press the delete button in the post menu under the post

Comment: @TinyGiant I don't know if that's really the right action. As mentioned that's disrespectful against the answerer.

Comment: @ΓιαννηςΑντωνιου You mentioned that answer was helpful for you, so why do you want to delete your question??

Answer (score 2):

A better way is to read the the integers as input and then make the calculation.
It is not a practical way to store the values in memory and then read them to 
make the calculation.If you don't want to read the numbers as input , I recommend you to use li instruction to load a specific numeric value into your registers and then proceed to the calculation you may want.

```
.data
strin: .asciiz "type two integers\n"
strout: .asciiz "the result of the substract is:"

.text
.globl main
main:

li $v0, 4
la $a0,strin                                                                 
syscall

#changed
li $v0, 5        #Read the first integer
syscall
move $t0,$v0     #move the value you read to $t0 register

#changed
li $v0, 5       #Read the second integer
syscall
move $t1,$v0    #move the value you read to $t1 register

sub $s0,$t0,$t1    #make substraction between $t0 and $t1 and store the        
                   #result in $s0 register       
li $v0, 4
la $a0,strout                                                                                   
syscall

li $v0, 1
move $a0, $s0
syscall

li $v0,10
syscall
```

Comment: This would be a better answer if you at least put a comment in the code describing what you changed and why.

Comment: You could do the `sub` after printing `the result of the substract is:`, then you could save a `move` instruction and put the subtract result right into `$a0` for the syscall that prints it.

Comment: Den kanei tipota!